# Why can't I get the right answer in this SQLzoo tutorial?

Tags: sql, mysql-5.0

[Problem 2b](http://sqlzoo.net/2b.htm) goes as follows:

> 2b. For each subject show the first year that the prize was awarded.
>
> > nobel(yr, subject, winner)

My solution was this:

    `SELECT DISTINCT subject, yr

    FROM nobel

    ORDER BY yr ASC;`

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer gets a row for every distinct combination of subject and year.

The correct answer GROUPS BY the subject, and gets the MIN year per subject.

Enough of a clue?

Comment: SELECT subject, min(yr)
FROM nobel
GROUP BY subject;

Comment: SELECT subject, MIN(yr) AS yr FROM nobel GROUP BY subject ORDER BY yr

Comment: "AS" names the column, so instead of some default like "Expr1" you get "yr"

Answer (score 4):

You could do it a different way without using group by or min

```
select distinct subject, yr from nobel x
  where yr <= all
    (select yr from nobel y
     where y.subject = x.subject)
```

but its definitely more work.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT subject, MIN(yr)
FROM nobel
GROUP BY subject;
```

Yay!